# How to be sure about an uploaded file is not a virus in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, security, file-upload, webforms

I saw this question:

[ASP.NET File Upload: how can I make sure that an uploaded file is really a JPEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527092/asp-net-file-upload-how-can-i-make-sure-that-an-uploaded-file-is-really-a-jpeg)

and similar questions about being sure of the file being uploaded through asp:FileUpload control in ASP.net is really image. But What If users upload virus-infected images? How can I be insured of the image files being uploaded via my ASP.net application does not affect the files in my web app folder and/or images uploaded by other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't serve it back to anyone as anything other than an image (content-type) and never trying to execute (.exe) the file you'll be fine.

Comment: How much can I count on your words Matt? Are you sure about this?

Comment: are you going to execute anything they upload to you?  Are you going to ask any of your users to execute something you have served?  If No && No Then Safe!

Answer (score 1):

Most anti-virus software run whats known as an "on-access scan". That is, when a file is changed, it automatically scans that file.

So save that file to the file system and let your server's anti-virus software do the work for you.

Comment: So isn't there any way I can force a kind of encapsulation to a file that is being uploaded?

Comment: Sure. I'm going to let my users add images via a fileupload control. I affraid that they upload dangerous files with file headers similar to normal images to do terrible things on the place they are placed in the server (e.g. deleting the whole application folder) and I'm afraid of solely relying on the power of server's anti-virus software.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take what is likely a somewhat controversial position.

There is no way to know with 100% certainty what the intent of a file is, be it good or evil. It is impossible. AV scanners give you a slice of data but they can't give you 100% guarantees either. No one can.

Given this reality, you need to build your app assuming that all files uploaded are bad. Yes, scanning is still fine and will filter out a bunch of stuff. But it will never be 100%. Is it 99.999% or 20%? Who knows. Does it really matter?

I would build any app today assuming that all user supplied content is bad. Very bad. Hostile bad. Because eventually it will be if you make it. And when it is, you'll be ready for them...rather than all the people that have to rearchitect their app because they made bad assumptions early on.

With a bit more data about your exact concerns, I'd be happy to comment on them more specifically...

Comment: Dear Eric, here are my concerns: I'm going to let my users add images via a fileupload control. I affraid that they upload dangerous files with file headers similar to normal images to do terrible things on the place they are placed in the server (e.g. deleting the whole application folder) and I'm afraid of solely relying on the power of server's anti-virus software.

Comment: Treat the files like byte arrays. Don't ever run them through an engine that parses them or could otherwise be exploited by looking at them. To avoid accidental double clicks I'd recommend changing file extensions and names. Heck you could even tweak the format so they can't be opened w/o going through your stack. I'd also note that even running them through AV presents risk. AV engines have had security issues too.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, In older version of `IIS (6 or prior versions)` It could be possible to change `FileName` to the real malicious file name after save the file with original filename. **Which has possibility to be read and execute regularly by the server**.
E.G. set the file name like: `file.asp;.jpg` or `file.asp%00.jpg` etc...
It also has a possibility to change target directory by manipulation of file name. **Which is extremely dangerous**
E.G. `newfolder.asp::$Index_Allocation` or etc...
There is also some new way of attacks.  [Read](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload) more here.